# Export only certain commands in custom package

Tags: macros, packages

I'm making my first attempts at making a custom `.sty` and I was wondering if there was a way to make certain new commands, though usable within the file itself, unavailable to someone importing the package. For instance, if my `.sty` file reads as

```
\NeedsTEXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{example}{YYYY/MM/DD Example Package}

\newcommand{helpercommand}{...}

\newenvironment{mainenvironment}{
    some things using \helpercommand
}{...}
```

is there a way for me to allow a user importing this package to have access to the `mainenvironment` but not the `helpercommand`? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know I could define `helpercommand` within `mainenvironment` but I believe this is the only way for me to do this in the particular case I have, and in any case, I would like to know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: no but the usual convention is to call your internal helper `\ENPM@helpercommand`  not `\helpercommand`  which doesn't prevent anyone using it but prevents them using it _by accident_.

Comment: You could use a double-secret-cross-my-fingers optional-argument key to load certain code, as in `\usepackage[akakadak]{mypackage}`

Comment: A package is just a text file. As long as somebody has a copy of this textfile, he can read it and see what the commands are doing and use them. So the question is: How can i prevent a user from using a helper commands as a document command, i guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you change the switch to `\makeletter`. now you can use your secret commands with `@` like `mycom@nd` and public commands without `@`. by the end, you switch back to `\makeother`

Comment: the OP showed code in a package so makeatletter is already implicitly applied.